# xkbcommon: ERROR: xkb_x11_keymap_new_from_device: illegal device ID: -1

Tags: vnc, xkb

When trying to start `x-window-manager` (which links to `/usr/bin/mutter`, version 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2) in `xstartup` in a vnc4server session, I get this error:

```
xkbcommon: ERROR: xkb_x11_keymap_new_from_device: illegal device ID: -1
xkbcommon: ERROR: xkb_x11_state_new_from_device: illegal device ID: -1Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Install xfce4 (`sudo apt-get install xfce4`) and use this `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Don't forget to make it executable. Check `~/.vnc/*.log` for errors.

Comment: +1 This worked for me.